# CDI inject a @PersistenceContext based on user input

Tags: jpa, cdi, inject

I'm trying to figure out how to do with with CDI.  I'm working on an application where users are able to connect to multiple databases.  The Application asks which they want to connect to and they can also disconnect and connect to a different database.  This is a Java SE application using Seam for CDI and Hibernate for JPA.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to leverage CDI to wire up @PersistenceContext but also make it dynamic so different databases can be accessed.  I'm just not sure the pattern or technique I would use to do this with CDI.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I figured out what I wanted to do by using `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance`.  First define a simple bean:

```
@Alternative
public class Foo {
    private int value;

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

It is defined as an `@Alternative` so CDI doesn't get confused between this and the producer method (shown next).  A better solution would be too define `Foo` as an interface then `FooImpl` would be annotated with `@Typed` so CDI thinks it's only a `FooImpl` bean type.  Anyway, next is a producer class.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FooProducer {
    private int value;
    public FooProducer() {
        value = -1;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Produces
    public Foo getFoo() {
        Foo p = new Foo();
        p.setValue(getValue());
        return p;
    }
}
```

The `getFoo()` method produces a new `Foo` object with different values.  The value can be changed by the `setValue(int)` method.  Next I use the `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance` to inject `Foo`.

```
@Inject
Instance<Foo> fooInstance;

@Inject
FooProducer fooProducer;

....

fooProducer.setValue(10);

Foo foo = fooInstance.get();
System.out.printf("foo = %s, %d\n", foo.getValue());

fooProducer.setValue(10000);

foo = fooInstance.get();
System.out.printf("foo = %s, %d\n", foo.getValue());
```

Here I use the injected `fooProducer.setValue()` method to change how the producer will produce `Foo`. When `fooInstance.get()` is called the first time `Foo` will contain the value 10 and the second time it will have the value 10000.

Given this simple example, it is easy to apply to getting `EntityManager` instances to different databases at runtime.  There is a bit more to the code which produces the `EntityManager` but not too much.

Answer (score 0):

PersistenceContext is handled by an EJB container. Since you are not in an EJB container, forget the persistence context and consider using CDI producers.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerFactoryProvider {

  private EntityManagerFactory emf;

  public void voidApplicationEMF() {
    //load the EMF here based on dynamic properties
    this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactpry(Map of loaded properties);
  }

  @Produces
  public EntityManager em() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
  }
}
```

Then somewhere in your code

```
@SessionScoped
public class MyEntityController {
  @Inject
  private EntityManager emf;
}
```

There are still issues to deal with transactions etc.

In a JSE environment, you must explicitly start and commit/rollback transactions.
Since you are using CDI, you can use Interceptors to start-of/check for transaction status and rollback/commit as necessary.

```
@Interceptor
public class MyInterceptor {
  @Inject
  private EntityManager em;

  @AroundInvoke
  public Object intercept(InvocationContext ic) {
    try {
      //initiate transaction
      em.getTransaction().start ....
      return ic.proceed();
    }catch(Exception ex) { //rollback if necessary }
    finally {//commit transaction if necessary }
  }
}
```

Comment: >`PersistenceContext is handled by an EJB container` - This is not correct. JPA is a separate spec from EJB, and the persistence context is typically set by the Java EE container specific part of the JPA implementation.

Comment: @ArjanTijms actually JPA spec is part of EJB spec, only the spec document is separated

Comment: I'm not clear on how to implement the part you comment as "//load the EMF here based on dynamic properties" I don't want the producer class to be responsible for the user interface. I'm trying to figure out the MVC way - the view deals with getting the dynamic info then somehow passing it to the producer. Now that I'm thinking through this while I'm typing, perhaps CDI events are the way to go? The producer class observes an event and sets the dynamic data in the producer class used when producing the EntityManager? How would injection points get updated when the database changes?

Comment: That could be a valid option if the db properties come from the end-user interface (I hope it is not public interface: sql injection....)

Comment: >"actually JPA spec is part of EJB spec, only the spec document is separated" - Why do you think this? JPA was only briefly part of the EJB spec in Java EE 5/EJB 3.0. It became its own spec in Java EE 6/EJB 3.1 with JSR 317. See https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317